# Same File not uploading second time ajax php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Whenever I'm uploading an mp3 file for the second time, the file is then not uploaded to the server. I don't receive any error messages. Any idea what's going wrong?

Here is my code:

```js
$("#fileToUploads").on("change ", function(e) {
  var file_data = $('#fileToUploads').prop('files')[0];
  var form_data = new FormData();
  form_data.append('fileToUploads', file_data);
  $.ajax({
    url: "modules/phone/newholdmusic.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: form_data,
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    beforeSend: function() {
      $("#loading-images").show();
    },
    success: function(response) {
      $("#selnames").html(response);
      $("#loading-images").hide();
      $("#fileToUploads").val('');
      $("#fileToUploads").val("");
      setTimeout(function() {
        $('#selnames').fadeOut();
      }, 5000);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<form name="holdmusicform" id="holdmusicform" action="modules/phone/holdmusics.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-inline for-frm" onsubmit="return validatemusicForm()">
  <input type="file" name="fileToUploads" id="fileToUploads">
</form>
```

Comment: please also share `modules/phone/newholdmusic.php` ?

Comment: share php code. i think you will not used random name for mp3 file and second time your file name is same

Comment: Do you get any error messages? Can you provide the code from "modules/phone/newholdmusic.php" ?

Comment: @BilalAhmed    my newholdmusic code is below

$src = $_FILES['fileToUploads']['tmp_name'];
 echo $file_name = $_FILES['fileToUploads']['name'];
 $file_size =$_FILES['fileToUploads']['size'];
 $file_tmp =$_FILES['fileToUploads']['tmp_name'];
 $file_type=$_FILES['fileToUploads']['type'];
 $valid_extension = array('.mp3', '.mp4', '.wav');
 $file_extension = strtolower( strrchr( $_FILES["fileToUploads"]["name"], "." ) );

 if( in_array( $file_extension, $valid_extension )){
   move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"holdmusic/".$file_name);
   }

Comment: edit your question and add this code in the question, in comments this code is not readable

Comment: @BilalAhmed : because of length i cant edit in question

Comment: @komalverma I'm pretty sure you can edit your original post

Comment: found the php code in the edits, apparently someone deleted it by mistake. I think the file is uploaded the second time, but since both files have the same name, you are replacing the first file with the second

Answer (score 0):

please do the below change use live function

```
$("#fileToUploads").on("change ", function(e) {
```

to

```
$("#fileToUploads").live('change', function() {
```

Comment: The `.live` functions is deprecated as of JQuery 1.7 and will be removed in 1.9. You also suggest to change from  id `#fileToUploads` to class `.fileToUploads` which would not work in this case